# run php webpage from discord.js

Tags: php, node.js

I'm making a bot where if you do /run it will make an api request and start a web based action but i need to run the page from a node.js command what i have currently is

```
 var request = require('request');
 request('http://example.com/?ip=xxx-xxx-xxx', function (error, response, 
  body) {
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
 }
 })
```

but this doesn't seem to work...

How would I go about doing this ?

EDIT: It was cloudflare blocking access

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you getting an error? What is printed in the console?

Comment: Apparently it was cloudflare blocking access